# Django unable to upload image using multipart/form-data

Tags: django

I am trying to upload a profile image for my user model on user registration,
but the image is not getting saved at the media folder,
and the default image is displayed.
(When I edit the user's image in django admin, it gets saved).
Where am I causing this problem, and how to fix it?

My register function in views.py:

```py
def register(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm()
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('account:login')

    context = {'form': form}

    return render(request, 'account/register.html', context)
```

My register.html file:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %} {% block contents %}
<h1>Register</h1>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
{% csrf_token %} {{form.as_p}}

<input type="submit" name="Create User" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

My user creation form:

```py
class UserCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(
    label='Password confirmation', widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('email', 'username', 'date_of_birth', 'profile_image')

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get("password1")
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get("password2")
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data["password1"])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

And my User model:

```py
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, date_of_birth, password, profile_image):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username = username,
            date_of_birth= date_of_birth,
            profile_image = profile_image,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pic', default='/profile_pic/default.jpg')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploaded file data is found in [`request.FILES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES), you need to pass this to your form along with the POST data [when handling file uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/file-uploads/)

```
form = UserCreationForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

Answer (score 0):

A view handling this form will receive the file data in `request.FILES`, which is a dictionary containing a key for each `FileField` (or `ImageField`, or other `FileField` subclass) in the form. So the data from the above form would be accessible as `request.FILES['file']`.

Official Example -

```
def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```

In your case, you can use:

```
form = UserCreationForm(request.POST, , request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('account:login')
```

Notice that we have to pass request.FILES into the form’s constructor; this is how file data gets bound into a form.